# what is hypothesis testing?

Tags: statistics, ab-testing, abtest

p-value? parameter tests?

I tried to solve it but I couldn’t.

An online retail company performed an A/B test to check whether changing the size of the cart icon increases the expected number of items added to the cart before either placing an order or leaving the website. Here are the number of items added to the cart of the first 10 users in the two groups, control (A) and treatment (B):

Answer (score 0):

Under the alternative H1, we expect a different distribution
for the test statistic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

we expect a different distribution for the test statistic1 Under the alternative H1,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

chatgpt
i m using
H0 (Null Hypothesis) : μ_treatment = μ_control

μ_treatment is mean number of hours watched by treatment group.

μ_control is mean number of hours watched by the control group

Null Hypothesis is there is no difference in the mean between both of the groups.

H1(Alternate Hypothesis) : μ_control ≠ μ_treatment

Alternate Hypothesis is that there is a difference between number of hours of both the groups. In this case we are checking for the 2sided test as we donot know.